# eval returning undefined, browser returning a result

Tags: javascript, eval

I've got a javascript string such as the following:

```
"h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o")
```

If I save the string to a variable and eval it, it returns as undefined:

```
var str = "h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o");
var x = eval (str);
console.log(x) // undefined
```

However, if I paste the string into the Chrome JS console, it returns as expected:

```
"hello"
```

Any reason why eval would return undefined, and how is the JS console accomplishing the feat?

Thanks!

Comment: you are doing `console.log(str)` not `console.log(x)` your comma operators make the example rather confusing though...

Comment: What did you expect `hello` to return?

Comment: exactly that, the string 'hello', i.e. the product of the concatenation

Comment: So you expect `eval()` to do nothing? `console.log("hello")` should be identical to `console.log(eval("hello"))`?

Comment: Seems i misunderstood what eval was doing tbh. As per Quentin, I should have assigned the string to get my result.

Comment: @m0atz, eval'ing the string `hello` would be exactly the same as typing the word `hello` in the console. Unless it's been defined as a variable somewhere else, you are going to get a reference error. Perhaps what you wanted to go was the equivalent of `eval("'hello'")`, which will return the string `'hello'`. So, for example, make your string `var str = "'h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o'");` and it'll do what you expected

Comment: @MattBurland that's a great answer thank you. I've now got exactly what I needed. Firstly assigning my string to a variable .toString() and then eval'ing that. Works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `"h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o")` evaluates as the string `"hello"`.

If you paste that into the Chrome console, then you get what it evaluates to displayed.

If you pass it to `eval` then the expression evaluates to the string `"hello"` and then eval takes that string and evaluates to the *variable name* `hello` which isn't defined.

If you just want to get `"hello"` into a variable, then don't use `eval`, use an assignment.

```
var x = "h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o");
console.log(x);
```

Comment: ah! that's where I was getting confused. Now I get it, thanks!

Comment: additional issue im running up against - if i hard-code the "h" + "e" ... string as above, the assignment works perfect. If I obtain the string via extracting it from a regex and call this y, assigning x = y and printing x to the console returns the original string still and not "hello"

Comment: @m0atz — If you have a new question, then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question and include [a proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It sounds like you are using the regex improperly, but I've no way to tell in what way from that vague description of the code.

Comment: I actually have asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35640372/js-regex-result-expression-assignment-issue . Thanks for your assistance, but it seems from the answer given in the new question the issue is the string is enclosed in quotes which affects the output. No further work required sir, I think I have enough to get moving.

Answer (score 0):

When you paste the string into the console, it immediately evaluates the operations you have defined, thus you get the proper

```
"hello"
```

result. When you go to eval, however, you should see "ReferenceError: hello is not defined." This is because the string operations have again been immediately resolved, so your call to eval becomes

```
eval('hello')
```

which is meaningless.