# js regex result expression assignment issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a js string, for example:

```
"h" + "e" + "l" + "l" + "o"
```

which is being derived from a regex query. The string appears between [..] therefore I'm using the following to derive it:

```
var txt = '"blahblahblah["h"+"e"+"l"+"l"+"o"]foobarfoobarr"';
var re = /[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g;
var squareParen = re.exec(txt); // squareParen[0] contains ' "h" + "e".. etc'

// i assumed by assigning the string to a var 
// it would show me the product of its output
var result = squareParen[0];
console.log (result);
```

now, following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639254/eval-returning-undefined-browser-returning-a-result), if I hard code my string (as a test) and assign it, when I output to console it reads 'hello' as expected. However, when I use the output of the regex query assigned to a variable, it's outputting the result as is, i.e. "h"+"e"+"l"+"l"+"o" and not "hello".

I'm confused as to why.

Comment: Because your regex matches anything between `[]`. Try fiddling with it [here](https://regex101.com/#javascript) to understand why.

Comment: Does using `var result = squareParen[0].replace(/"([^"])"\+?/g,'$1');` solve the issue?

Comment: interesting. it does for my test string "h"+"e"...etc. i'm keen to know why that is. for my actual values extracted from regex, they can contain other parens, curly and round which may affect this however.

Comment: If you need a solution, please post the requirements. One example is not enough.

Comment: totally agree. you have given me much more than i expected to be honest, coupled with the answer below i have what i need sir.

Comment: out of interest another example would be ["h" + "e" + "l" + ("foo", "bar", "l") + ("abc", "def", "o")]

Comment: You need to use `@`+username to let the user know you have a message for them - I came back here by chance. What is the expected output for the above?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the expected output of the above is "hello". thanks for the tip about '@ + user'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you're storing in `result` is actually a string that looks like:

```
'"h"+"e"+"l"+"l"+"o"'
```

Which is distinct from the *expression* `"h"+"e"+"l"+"l"+"o"`; that expression is a series of string concatenations which evaluates to the string `"hello"`.

Be cautious about using the output from `console.log` as a definitive guide; it renders the given values in a way that aesthetically valuable, but not always precise.

I'm curious what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: now that makes sense! console.log has been lying haha. i'm playing around with some deobfuscation.

Comment: what other debugging method would you suggest in this instance outside of console.log

Comment: as a general rule, logging is a poor substitute for debugging. For javascript specifically, simply use the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement